# Maintain Form selection in php

Tags: php, ajax

We have a php form with a Division drop down, which when selected populates a SubDivision drop down using an onChange event and an ajax call

The initial run works fine, but if you click the BACK button to make corrections - issues arise. The division field is kept, but the SubDivision is now blank. And, because it gets populated with onChange, I have to Change the Division to something else THEN change it back to show the correct list of SubDivisions.

Is there a way to maintain the subDivision field on the form when the BACK button is used? We want the page to go to a 2nd screen where they can review their selections. If something looks incorrect, they need to have the option to go back and makes changes or corrections.

Here is the initial form code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div>Nominator's Division<span class="red">*</span> </div>
      <div><select id="NomDivision" name="NomDivision">
           <option value=""> -- Please Select -- </option>
           <?php echo $data->GetDivisions(); ?>
           </select>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
      <div>Nominator's Unit<span class="red">*</span> </div>
      <div><select id="NomUnit" name="NomUnit">
      <option value=""> -- Please Select -- </option>
      </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

Then the onChange that populates the unit:

```
$('#NomDivision').on('change', function(){
            var id = this.value;
            $.ajax({ url: "classes/ajax_calls.php?f=getsubdivisions&id=" + id, type: "GET", dataType: 'html',
                error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown); },
                success: function(subDivisions){ $("#NomUnit").append('<option value=""> -- Please Select -- </option>').html(subDivisions); }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not get back button working, so found a simple work around. On the form submit I just added a target="_blank" to open the preview page on a new tab thus leaving all the info on the prior page. Then, instead of having the back button issue, they just close that tab to return to the prior page where all the form information (including the selections for all 5 drop downs) is still intact.